# Exception when moving Data from DataTable to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx

In the following code, the statement which is commented throws an exception

```
try {
    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
        for(int i=1; i<NumColumns+1; i++) {

            // this statement throws 
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, i].value=dr[i - 1].ToString();

        }
        rowCount+=1;
    }

}
catch(Exception) {
    throw;
}
```

The data it is trying to move is the following:

> === 3 ===

Here is a screenshot of where it gets up to:

[image: UdScI.png]

Is this solvable? Or do I need to research using other tools to move data into Excel (such as closedXML)?

Comment: I tend to use `get_Range().Value2` to set cell values, instead of the `Cells` property. Example: `xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1").Value2 = "data";` The only problem in your case is that you'll need to convert the column number to a column name, but that is easily done.

Comment: See my answer here for converting a column number into an Excel column name: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/14059604/976080](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14059604/976080)

Comment: @SidHolland `cells` and `range` are very similar - most of my experience is using excel-vba and both of these classes are used a lot...I tend more towards cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the string **start with an equal sign**, that would expect creating a *formula*. You can use an apostrophe then equal sign(that is, start with `'=`).

Your original string might cause a `COMException` with `HRESULT:0x800A03EC` as following screenshot shown:

[image: 43uKH.jpg]

With the following code I've tested, has no problem with the data such as

> '=== 3 ===

Code:

```
namespace TestNamespace {
    using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    public static class TestClass {
        static DataTable BuildTestDataTable() {
            var dt=new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Memo", typeof(String));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Leon Scott Kennedy", 36, "M", "'=== 1 ===" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Ada Wong", 39, "F", "'=== 3 ===" });
            return dt;
        }

        public static void ExportToExcel(this DataTable dt, String fileName) {
            var xlApp=new Excel.ApplicationClass();

            var xlWorkBook=xlApp.Workbooks.Open(
                fileName,
                0,
                false, // for read/write
                5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,
                "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0
                );

            var xlWorkSheet=(Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1];
            var NumColumns=dt.Columns.Count;
            var rowCount=dt.Rows.Count;

            try {
                foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
                    for(int i=1; i<NumColumns+1; i++) {
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, i]=dr[i-1].ToString();
                    }
                    rowCount+=1;
                }

                xlWorkBook.Save();
            }
            catch(Exception) {
                throw;
            }
            finally {
                xlApp.Quit();
            }
        }

        public static void TestMethod() {
            TestClass.BuildTestDataTable().ExportToExcel(@"c:\ExistingFile.xlsx");
            // TestClass.BuildTestDataTable().ExportToExcel(@"c:\ExistingFile.xls");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try - why will this help?

Comment: try entering this ====3==== into a cell in Excel ....that is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
public void ExporttoExcel(DataTable table,string type)
    {

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+ type +".xls");
       // HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Reports.doc");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<font style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<BR><BR><BR>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Table border='1' bgColor='#ffffff' borderColor='#000000' cellSpacing='2' cellPadding='2' style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Arial; background:white;'> <TR>");
        int columnscount = table.Columns.Count;

        for (int j = 0; j < columnscount; j++)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<B>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(table.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</B>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<TR>");
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(row[i].ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Table>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</font>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: +1 for the extra xml option **BUT** I want to export to an `xlsx` file that is part of the current Solution - into a specific worksheet in that template....does your answer do this?